# Functions missing after assigning values to Object

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am working on a rest api using node, express and typeorm. 
I have a User entity:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  Unique,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn
} from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export enum userRole {
  ADMIN = "ADMIN",
  USER = "USER"
}

@Entity()
@Unique(["username"])
export class User[![enter image description here][1]][1] {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50 })
  username: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 255 })
  password: string;

  @Column({ type: "enum", enum: userRole })
  role: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: "created_at" })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: "updated_at" })
  updatedAt: Date;

  hashPassword() {
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
  }

  checkIfUnencryptedPasswordIsValid(unencryptedPassword: string) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(unencryptedPassword, this.password);
  }
}
```

And the repository function to save a user:

```
export const register = async userData => {
  let user = new User();

  // THIS CODE WORKS AS EXPECTED
  // BUT IS TEDIOUS TO ASSIGN EACH PROPERTY ONE BY ONE
  // user.username = userData.username;
  // user.password = userData.password;
  // user.role = userData.role;

  // I WAS TRYING WITH SPREAD, BUT NO LUCK
  user = { ...userData };

  // BECAUSE, THEN IT SAYS THAT THE user DOESN'T HAVE
  // THE hashPassword METHOD
  user.hashPassword();
  const userRepository = getRepository(User);
  await userRepository.save(user);
};
```

So, at first I create a user from User entity, to set with new values and then store in database.

But, after using the spread operator to avoid setting each attribute one by one, the new user doesn't have the methods it had in the beginning (hashPassword, checkIfUnencryptedPasswordIsValid).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround.
In the user entity I added a constructor to iterate through the properties coming from the service.

```
constructor(params?: User) {
    for (const key in params) {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this[key] = params[key];
      }
    }
  }
```

These options can also be optional if you only want to instantiate an empty User object.

And, in the userRepository, the register function is as:

```
export const register = async (userData: User) => {
  const user = new User(userData);
  await user.hashPassword();
  const userRepository = getRepository(User);
  await userRepository.save(user);
};
```

So now, both methods and properties are available and the code is simple and clear.